# Deleting replogs generated by Datastax Advanced Replication

Tags: replication, datastax, database-replication

I have a replication set up between two datastax clusters for a table. I have now deleted the replication channel since I no longer need data replicated. 
The channel had generated a large number of replogs which were yet to be transmitted, but is no longer required (since the replication has been terminated). 
Can I go ahead and remove those files? Is there any datastax command which performs such a cleanup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked to the official documentation on the [disable the advanced replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/advReplication/advRepOperations.html#advRepOperations__stop)? If you didn't delete the channels already, you simply were need to stop replication and truncate unreplicated data with [dse advrep channel truncate](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/advReplication/commands/dseAdvrepChannelTruncate.html).

In case if you dropped the channels, then I go the road of disabling this feature as disabling the advanced replication as described in documentation, and when restarting the node, remove the files from the disk... And after you restart all nodes, then you can drop `dse_advrep` keyspace.

Comment: Since the channel has already been dropped, dse advrep channel truncate is not an option. I reached out to datastax forums and was informed it is safe to delete the replog files. Datastax engineers have updated that documentation will be extended to include steps for retiring advanced replication channels.

Comment: yep - that's what I meant in the 2nd paragraph ;-)